# What's the minimum latency achievable for a shared drive?

Tags: storage

I have a server application that uses an on-disk cache for certain data (100GB-1TB of it). Now I want to use multiple instances (10, 100) of the server application (each on a separate server), and all of them will pretty much generate the same cache contents.

Now an obvious thought is to share the cache between all these machines. However, my cached items are small (10kb). Therefore I need - above all - low latency on access to cache items.

What is the fastest way of providing such a shared cache in terms of latency? Obviously, CIFS over Ethernet doesn't really cut it.

If it helps, you can assume that all my servers are VMs on the same host system, so if nifty VMware features exist (or similar stuff), I'm all ears.

Comment: Voting to close as too broad because engineering storage systems is an entire field of study.  Basically, the minimum latency boils down to: "How much money do you have?"

Comment: Lots of tiny files in a filesystem is generally awful, you would be better off using a nosql document store if it suits your usage.

Comment: I disagree- I think this is on topic. Maybe badly worded, but what's really being asked here is how to minimize latency for file access between VMs in the same hypervisor.

Comment: Basil - you are right, that's what I'm trying to understand. Actually thought that that would be too specific, so I tried to be broader to make the question useful to others. Apparently not very successfully.

Answer (score 2):

Your sources of latency are several:

- Drive storage-io stack latency on whatever is hosting the storage.

  - This ranges from sub-millisecond to 10's of milliseconds, or even 100's of milliseconds for really loaded systems.
- Network-FS stack latency for whatever method you're serving this up (CIFS, NFS, OpenSwift, Gluster, whatever)

  - For connection-oriented protocols (CIFS, NFS) this rarely exceeds 10ms, and often less than 1ms.
  - For connectonless protocols (OpenSwift) the TCP handshake has to take place which is a function of network diameter.
- Network distance latency

  - For networks as close as you describe, this is likely less than 1ms.
- Network-client latency

  - Less than 1ms for unloaded systems.

All in all, your biggest sources of latency are going to be the actual performance of the storage subsystem and your choice of protocol. I'd go with a connection-oriented storage protocol. Considering you're looking at "100's" for concurrent connections, I'd go with something that the kernel of whatever you're using handles in-kernel if at all possible.

Really, the fastest way to cut latency is to put it all on SSDs.